# No puedo encontrar texto entre dos palabras con expresiones regulares - Python3

Tags: python

Python 3.7

Hola, estoy desarrollando un Script en Python con la finalidad de encontrar comentarios en HTML.

Estoy utilizando expresiones regulares, intentando identificar las lineas HTML que comiencen por "

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, re, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
#import pandas as pandas


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("\n[*] Usage: Python " + sys.argv[0] + " <url>\n")
    sys.exit(1)

url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for i in soup:
    if re.findall('^<!--',i):
        print(i)
```

Al ejecutarlo, obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Espero me puedan ayudar, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: No tiene sentido que iteres sobre soup, si quieres hacer una búsqueda por eiquetas html parsea primero con BS buscando lo que necesites, si solo vas a buscar expresions en el html aplica la expresión sobre la salida de requests simplemente.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in soup:
    if(re.findall(r"^<!--",str(i))):
        print(i)
```

Si te das cuenta se parsea a `str()` para asegurar que sea una string lo que estas comparando y tambien verifica que no te este llegando una lista o diccionario por parte de soup.

Comment: Hola, al modificar el código de esa forma, solo obtuve una linea en blanco sin texto.
al imprimir el texto sin la expresión regular, lo muestra completo sin formato de lista.

Comment: Entiendo, en este caso ¿cual seria un valor de `i`? para determinar si el error esta en la expresion, en el findall o bien en la condicional

Comment: i corresponde a cada fila del HTML.

Comment: Al momento de quitar la expresión regular y solo imprimir la variable i, se muestra el HTML completo.

Comment: Por que no mejor lo haces con `soup.find('<!--')` podria funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import  requests
#import pandas as pandas


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("\n[*] Usage: Python " + sys.argv[0] + " <url>\n")
    sys.exit(1)

url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
text = str(soup).split("\n")


for i in text:
    if re.findall(r"^<!--",str(i)):
        print(i)
```

El código, ya está funcional.